# How to get client Encoding?

Tags: jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I'm writing a jsp website in which I get a query from client. I have to normalize the encoding of the query, I mean I should change the query from its encoding to UTF-16. Because of that, I need to know the encoding of the client.

Does browsers send this information on the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getCharacterEncoding%28%29)

Comment: but I always get a null from this function, why?

Comment: the client has not sent any encoding

Comment: and I need a reliable way to find the encoding. A 100% solution

Comment: if the client does not send it, there is no way to determine it. So you don't have a 100% solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jsp, you should try to use some usefull methods that java offers.

```
public Map getHeaderFields()
```

will give you a Map of all headers you are searching for..

Moreover you have:

```
 String getContentEncoding() 
          Returns the value of the content-encoding header field.

 String getContentType() 
          Returns the value of the content-type header field.

 String     getCharacterEncoding()
Returns the name of the character encoding used in the body of this request. This method returns null if the request does not specify a character encoding
```

Comment: Which class has these functions?

Comment: httpservletrequest and urlconnection